# jQuery: globalEval being called on script insert

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html piece inserted into the dom, using jQuery("body").append(elementBelow):

```
<div>...</div>
<script type="..."> 
  // and this is being executed through jQuery.globalEval() 
</script>
```

Why aren't the browser itself handling the executing as it should, when inserted into the dom? Why is jQuery executing this piece of code?

If jQuery is executing this, why is this code not executed also when added to the dom? The indirect method eval is the one being used in the globalEvent method:

```
// Evaluates a script in a global context
globalEval: function( code ) {
    var script,
        indirect = eval;

    code = jQuery.trim( code );

    if ( code ) {
        // If the code includes a valid, prologue position
        // strict mode pragma, execute code by injecting a
        // script tag into the document.
        if ( code.indexOf("use strict") === 1 ) {
            script = document.createElement("script");
            script.text = code;
            document.head.appendChild( script ).parentNode.removeChild( script );
        } else {
        // Otherwise, avoid the DOM node creation, insertion
        // and removal by using an indirect global eval

           // !!!!!!!!!!! ENDING UP HERE HERE!!!!!!!!
            indirect( code );
        }
    }
},
```

I am just trying to understand how this all works, as it is being eval:ed and inserted into the dom.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question. Are you asking why jQuery evals the script, even though the browser would eval it anyway if added to the DOM?

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, kind of. But the code is not running twice for some reason despite being added to the dom.

Comment: I believe because of https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L60-L75, applied here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L504. The `type` attribute is temporarily changed so that the `script` element is not interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why aren't the browser itself handling the executing as it should, when inserted into the dom? Why is jQuery executing this piece of code?

Because when you insert into the DOM via `innerHTML`, the browser doesn't execute `script` elements. So since that's frequently what people actually want, jQuery does it for you.

Comment: But when you simply append a `script` DOM element, the browser *does* execute it. So, I think the question still stands, why does jQuery eval the script for you?

Comment: @FelixKling I agree, jQuery won't do any magic if you are using body.innerHTML = ""; anyway. This just feels as potentially slower way to executed perfectly compliant way of execute scripts. This should at least be an option to disable. And I am using this on jQuery 2.x, which is supposed to target newer browsers

Comment: Just check doManip function which seems to do alot of stuff

Comment: @SecretService: It does indeed, but by and large what it does is set itself up so that it can use `innerHTML` without concerns (handling issues like not trying to insert `tr` elements into something that isn't a `tbody` or `thead`, etc.).